# Extending the base class of a flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter

Being new to Dart,  I am not sure how I could extend the class of my statefull widget. This is what one of my class looks like

```
class HomeState extends State<Home>
{
}
```

What I would like to do is to make the HomeState class inherit some methods from my custom class. Which would be something like this

```
class CustomClass
{
   void DisplayBusyDialog()
   {
         ......
   }
}
```

I know in Dart like Java you cannot inherit from multiple class (unlike C++).
My question is what would I need to do to have `HomeState` inherit from `CustomClass` ? Will my custom class need to inherit from StatefulWidget and then have `HomeState` class extend `CustomClass` ? what about the template State how do I handle that in my custom Class? Any suggestions would be appreciated ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you'll want is mixin, which allows multiple "extends".

```
class Bar {
  bar() {}
}

mixin Mixin {
  foo() {}
}

class Foo extends Bar with Mixin {
  hello() {
    foo();
    bar();
  }
}
```

And if you need your mixin the access fields from the base-class:

```
mixin Mixin on Bar {
  foo() {
    bar();
  }
}
```

Comment: can we have multiple mixins ?

Comment: sure ! just add a coma + the type of your second mixin

Comment: Seems like Mixins cant take constructors

Comment: They need to have a default constructor, yeah. But that's still the dart way of doing this kind of stuff.

Comment: How do you work with the children properties then? I want to be able to showSnackBar, which uses setState(), but can't do so without extending the State object

Comment: @Martin. Added an example

Comment: Wow that was fast. The problem is that mixin BaseState on State because it throws an error `error: Type parameters could not be inferred for the mixin 'BaseState' because no type parameter substitution could be found matching the mixin's supertype constraints (mixin_inference_no_possible_substitution at [mobile] lib/Screens/profile.dart:66)` (and `error: The class 'ProfileScreenState' cannot implement both 'State<ProfileScreen>' and 'State<StatefulWidget>' because the type arguments are different. (conflicting_generic_interfaces at [mobile] lib/Screens/profile.dart:66)`)

Comment: In case I mixin BaseState on State<ProfileScreen> it works properly, but only for ProfileScreen class

Answer (score 10):

According to Dart programming language, the `mixins` has the solution to extend multiple parent classes. Anyhow if you want to follow the traditional object-oriented concept you can create an abstract class with a generic type.

```
abstract class _BaseStatefulState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {

  _BaseStatefulState() {
    // Parent constructor
  }

  void baseMethod() {
    // Parent method
  }
}
```

Your `StatefulWidget` should be extended from the base like below:

```
class _MainScreenState extends _BaseStatefulState<MainScreen> {}
```

Example StatefulWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends _BaseStatefulState<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("Test")),
    );
  }
}

abstract class _BaseStatefulState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {

  _BaseStatefulState() {
    // Parent constructor
  }

  void baseMethod() {
    // Parent method
  }
}
```

Source reference: 
https://gist.github.com/aslamanver/e1360071f9caff009101eb190a38d4cb

Flutter mixin documentation: 
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins

Comment: I cant seem to put the _BaseStatefulState abstract class in another dart file... when i try to use it it will not import it. How do I do this? @Googlian

Comment: @ebg11 Can you specify your issue in another question clearly as mentioning this answer as a reference?

Comment: it worked for me thanks for the help
just in case if people get confused "_BaseStatefulState" is private class so to keep its code in a separate file and use it make it public by removing the underscore. Please mention it @Googlian

Comment: Make it public if you are using deicated file for the base class                         
                                                                                                                          
abstract class BaseStatefulState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {

  BaseStatefulState() {
    // Parent constructor
  }

  void baseMethod() {
    // Parent method
  }
}